# real time of setInterval

Tags: javascript, setinterval, timing

Is there any diffrence in intervals of those functions?

```
    function myIntervalFunction() {
        for(var c=1000000000000;c>0;--c) ;
    }

    setInterval(myIntervalFunction,1000);
```

and

```
    function myIntervalFunction() {
    }

    setInterval(myIntervalFunction,1000);
```

So does setInterval pauses javaScript for given interval or does it triggers after exact period of milliseconds?
After testing I think it takes longer if some code run, but I'm not sure. Could that be possible and if so how do i make it exact period?

Note: Instead of looping my code draws on a HTML5 canvas.

Comment: Yes there's a difference. The first one blocks all other JS when `myIntervalFunction` is executed (until the `for` loop completes, at least); the second does not. Remember, JavaScript is single-threaded.

Comment: Obviously, it is going to take longer to actually execute code, than it would to do nothing... the time it takes would be based on whatever is actually getting executed.

Comment: @Ian Technically, the second one blocks as well. But, since there is nothing in the method, it runs A LOT faster.

Comment: @Bic Absolutely, I didn't word that very well. I just meant that the first one will block a lot more, since it has the added `for` loop that the second doesn't. Any JavaScript code blocks other JavaScript code

Comment: `setInterval` basically just puts a function on the call stack to execute x milliseconds later – but if there is another function still running at that point, it can not be executed then, because JS is single-threaded. // If you want better control for timed animations, then look into `requestAnimationFrame`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setInterval` call will place your function in the callback queue for a timer but it's not guaranteed to hit the interval that you specify with great precision. Each JS engine implementation varies in how it implements the timers but most will probably have some sort of pooling of timer callbacks which means that it's hard to predict the exact variation between the desired interval and the actual interval between calls to your callback function.

And the resolution gets worse when you get down to the tens of milliseconds level.

If you're looking for a way to get constant frame rate for animation you may want to take a look at [this post](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/08/animating-with-javascript-from-setinterval-to-requestanimationframe/) that discusses using the [requestAnimationFrame API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame) available in modern borwsers.

Comment: requestAnimationFrame looks like a thing to go with, but it is a bit complicated. Thank you for quick response.